# Ionic : How to filter the list of other html content from index?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a beginner in ionic.

I have a search text box inside ion-nav-bar which is present in index.html. I am rendering enroutelist.html page in index which shows list of data. Here I want to search data which is present in enroutelist.html from index.html. So based on my input whatever am typing it has to filter and show the result.

I don't know how to pass data from index to enroutelist.html or is there any other way available?

Please can someone help me.

This is my index.html page

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive" ng-controller="ManiCntrl" align-title="center">

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<label class="item-input-wrapper tg-header-search" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..."  ng-model="search.storelist.store_name">
</label>

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<button class="button button-clear button-positive">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search custom-icon">
        </i>
    </button>
            <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="reset()">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-cart-outline custom-icon">
        </i>
    </button> 
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="reset()">
    <i class="icon ion-refresh custom-icon">
        </i>
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

This is my enroutelist.html code.

```
<ion-view class="enroute-view" view-title="ENROUTE">
<ion-content class="padding">
<button class="tab-btn" ng-click="listVisible()">
    <i class="ion-ios-list-outline">
        </i>
    </button>
     <button class="tab-btn">
    <i class="ion-ios-location">
        </i>
    </button>
    <br/><br/><br/>
 <ion-list ng-hide="registered">

 <ion-item class="store-item" ng-repeat="storelist in storelists">
  <span style="color: black; font-size: 16px;">{{storelist.store_name}}     </span><br/>
  <span style="font-size: 12px;">{{storelist.store_address}}</span>
  <i class="ion-ios-location custom-location">
  </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>  
 </ion-view>
```

Comment: You can use the `$rootScope`: `<input ng-model="$root.search" />` and `ng-repeat="storelist in storelists | filter:$root.search"`

Comment: @devqon I can't upvote. If you write it as answer then i can accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a 'root' search, you can use the `$rootScope` for that. Something like:

```
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..."
       ng-model="$root.search">
```

And then somewhere else on the page:

```
<ion-item class="store-item" ng-repeat="storelist in storelists | $root.search">
```